# Narrowing a generic return value in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes its arguments and returns a function that can work with those arguments.  Unfortunately, I can't get TypeScript to type-check it at all.  Here is a simplified example of my problem:

```
type NoiseMaker<T extends Animal> = (animal: T) => void;

class Dog  {
    bark() {
        console.log('Woof! Woof!');
    }
}

class Cat  {
    meow() {
        console.log('Meow')
    }
}

type Animal = Dog | Cat;

const bark: NoiseMaker<Dog> = (dog: Dog) => {
    dog.bark();
}

function getNoiseMaker<T extends Animal>(animal: T): NoiseMaker<T> {
    if (animal instanceof Dog) {
        // T is a Dog then, right?
        return bark;  // ERROR: Type '(dog: Dog) => void' is not assignable to type 'NoiseMaker<T>'.
                      // Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'Dog'
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("I don't know that kind of animal");
    }
}
```

`getNoiseMaker()` returns a function that should work for any given `T`.  Once TypeScript determines that the type of `T` is or extends Dog, why does it not allow me to return `bark`, which is a `NoiseMaker<Dog>`?

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Typescript does not do this kind of narrowing of generic parameters depending on code branches within the method. The `instanceof` type-guard will actually change only the type for `animal` from `T` to `T&Dog`, so it will impact the parameter but not the generic type.

The simplest solution would be to keep the generic signature as the public signature, but you a different implementation signature that allows you to write this code (you will loose some type safety inside the function, but publicly it will work exactly the same)

```
function getNoiseMaker<T extends Animal>(animal: T): NoiseMaker<T> 
function getNoiseMaker(animal: Animal): NoiseMaker<Animal> {
    if (animal instanceof Dog) {
        return bark;  // Ok
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("I don't know that kind of animal");
    }
}
```

Another option is to just cast `bark` to `any`

Comment: I was afraid of that.  I can also do return bark as NoiseMaker<T>.  But like you say, I lose some type safety in a place where I'd really like to have it.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: @user37078 Yes, a type assertion will fix the issue, not ideal but necessary in this case