# Why does function overload fix type-narrowing issue?

Tags: typescript, javascript-objects, type-narrowing

I have encountered an issue which basically involves narrowing the type returned from an object, accessed by its key. Let's say I have this an object whose values can be either `number` or `string`:

```
type Value = number | string;

enum DatumKey {
  numberDatum = 'numberDatum',
  stringDatum = 'stringDatum',
}

class DemoClass {
  private data = {
    [DatumKey.numberDatum]: 1337,
    [DatumKey.stringDatum]: 'foobar',
  }

  public getValue(key: DatumKey): Value {
    return this.data[key];
  }

  public doSomething(): void {
    const num: number = this.getValue(DatumKey.numberDatum); // TS expects `number | string`, I expect `number`
    const str: string = this.getValue(DatumKey.stringDatum); // TS expects `number | string`, I expect `string`

    console.log({ num, str });
  }
}

const dc = new DemoClass();
dc.doSomething();
```

[See Typescript Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=27&pc=18#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK7QLxQHZILYCMIBOUAPlAM7AECWGA5gNwBQjEW2UAInMDgNIQgoAb0ZRMOfAS4926AORtJ0nHIA0o8pRq1lsqHIrU6utYwC+zAMYI4ZMpwjYA9gGEbd4RrDUAbt2gAJtxwUOgiYmIA2rr8IAB0ioS6ALoAXFAAjADMWQDs6hFQ0dx8AnGG2inpcgBmTk64cASmYhZeSLgIVJZQtBDA8MgQABQA1gLpMQIAlOmDKJ6FBP1IBBhQwAAWVGRxQcBwkeMgyUytzGJgHV09AU4Ayk7Y-dt0w7NQPk5UAYsRlk4MBRxNh0okiOgtjs4n0BogUMMpvFwbppvQoAB6DFQAAq9ygEAAHpBLMB7AADcEkTRGWjk1RQACSBOJEFJUEpEkI5I0YgBQOANPSFTooQ2212sPmIyR5S0xhK2DRmOxeJZJLJHKppBFdIZzKJGo5up5vKg-LITgQEDiCCctGGQhBDMMUDMaI0FjaFsFAR66AwEAA7g5nG5bGR3kw-XsHk8Xtoo0A).

---

## Failed approach

So, in order to narrow the type, I have attempted to use a generic type, and I can then tell `getValue<...>()` what kind of type am I expecting in return:

```
public getValue<T extends Value>(key: DatumKey): T {
  // Error here: Type 'Value' not assignable to type 'T'
  return this.data[key];
}

public doSomething(): void {
  const num: number = this.getValue<number>(DatumKey.numberDatum); // TS expects `number`, it's good!
  const str: string = this.getValue<string>(DatumKey.stringDatum); // TS expects `string`, it's good!
}
```

However, by doing so, I get an error from TypeScript:

```
Type 'Value' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'Value' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
      'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.
```

[See Typescript Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=21&ssc=104&pln=20&pc=5#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK7QLxQHZILYCMIBOUAPlAM7AECWGA5gNwBQjEW2UAInMDgNIQgoAb0ZRMOfAS4926AORtJ0nHIA0o8pRq1lsqHIrU6utYwC+zAMYI4ZMpwjYA9gGEbd4RrDUAbt2gAJtxwUOgiYmIA2rr8IAB0ioS6ALoAXFAAjADMWQDs6hFQ0dx8AnGG2inpcgBmTk64cASmYhZeSLgIVJZQtBDA8MgQADwAKlAQAB7ArAH2gygAfAAUANYC6TECAJTp4+ERAPSHUACiBARORAAWhBB74NByCxBymE7AULZkVLQYcJ1oMAnFBQJB9KM5BoxAR+kgCBhQdcqGQ4kFgHBIusQMkmK1mGIwB0uj0Ak4AMpObD9ZF0Za7KA+JxUAKeQqWJwYCjibDpRJEdDAZGovoDRAoYb8lZbeL83TbehQY5QUbkiaTSCWYD2AAG-J1qigVGABl69QCAEJoVAOVzPoZ0hU6KEkSi4qKXsMnbRpSVsLFylpjH6FUqTqr1ZrtVAdd6DUaTfZaOardbbWQnAgIHEEE5aMshDzDYYoGYFRoLG1058Aj10BgIAB3BzONzfelMWtoilUmnaDtAA).

---

## Working approach

Then I came across a similar question here, which [suggested that the use of function overloads to fix the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48992141/narrowing-a-generic-return-value-in-typescript). It does. However, I am not sure why does a function overload fix the issue:

```
public getValue<T extends Value>(key: DatumKey): T 
public getValue(key: DatumKey): Value {
  return this.data[key];
}

public doSomething(): void {
  const num = this.getValue<number>(DatumKey.numberDatum); // TS expects `number`, it's good!
  const str = this.getValue<string>(DatumKey.stringDatum); // TS expects `string`, it's good!
}
```

[See Typescript Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK7QLxQHZILYCMIBOUAPlAM7AECWGA5gNwBQjEW2UAInMDgNIQgoAb0ZRMOfAS4926AORtJ0nHIA0o8pRq1lsqHIrU6utYwC+zAMYI4ZMpwjYA9gGEbd4RrDUAbt2gAJtxwUOgiYmIA2rr8IAB0ioS6ALoAXFAAjADMWQDs6hFQ0dx8AnGG2inpcgBmTk64cASmYhZeSLgIVJZQtBDA8MgQADwAKlAQAB7ArAH2gygAfAAUANYC6TECAJTp4+2d3b39CxBrG5wl2LG7sIgonoUE-UgEGFDAABZUZHFBwHBIusQMkmK1mGIwB0uj0Ak4AMpObD9b50Za3HxOKgBR4RSxODAUcR6L4-OJ9Ab3EaJAgrLbxGm6bb0KAAelZUFG8Imk0glmA9gABjTBaooFRgAZevUAgBCDRifGE4CaIjoUm-CmnYYVOh0q6xcpaYxXZlsjlcnl8gVQQW62ii8WS+y0GXyhVQJVkJwICBxBBOWjLITEsWGKBmZkaCxtL0qgI9dAYCAAdwczjctjI6KYCb+CKRKO0OaAA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your working solution does not really works. Variables `num` and `str` are typed as `Value` not as respectively `number` and `string`.

A more robust solution:

```
enum DatumKey {
  numberDatum = 'numberDatum',
  stringDatum = 'stringDatum',
}

const data = {
  [DatumKey.numberDatum]: 1337,
  [DatumKey.stringDatum]: 'foobar',
};

function getValue<T extends keyof typeof data>(key: T): (typeof data)[T] {
  return data[key];
}

// You don't have to explicitly type num and str. They are automatically inferred 
const num = getValue(DatumKey.numberDatum);
const str = getValue(DatumKey.stringDatum);
```

Comment: I would love to do this, but the matter of fact is that the `data` is a private property in a class, which means that I can't refer to it as `T extends keyof typeof this.data`, can I? Sorry if I was being unclear: I didn't know that `data` could be used in a way as such, therefore excluded the class example in my MCVE.

Comment: So maybe create an interface defining the type of Data.